# Exclude results of the first query on the second query in same table with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to do like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `langCategories` ORDER BY `name` ASC WHERE ORDER BY `amount` DESC LIMIT 8,0
```

but this is not posible.

I have 2 sections in my site:
**1. Top 8 Populars Categories**

```
(SELECT * FROM `langCategories` ORDER BY `langCategories`.`amount` DESC LIMIT 0,8)
```

**2. The rest of Categories order by name (excluding the top 8)**
(???)

I do it with php:

```
$var = db_multiselect("SELECT * FROM `langCategories` ORDER BY `amount` DESC LIMIT 0,8");
$var2 = db_multiselect("SELECT * FROM `langCategories` ORDER BY `name` ASC");

$i=-1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($var)) // Save the top8 categories
{
   ++$i;
   $top8[$i] = $row["name"];
}

$i=0;
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($var2))
{
   if (!(in_array($row2["name"], $top8))) // compare the rest of categories excluding top 8
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

But i want to do this with a MySQL Query, how can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subquery!

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `langCategories` 
  ORDER BY `langCategories`.`amount` DESC 
  LIMIT 8,2000000000
) AS baseview 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Gives you the NOT top 8 categories in alphabetical order

Comment: Criss-Cross: You were writing your comment, while I was editing the answer

Comment: oh ;) i see your answer is accepted, no need for single query instead of 2 i guess..

Answer (score 0):

this should work for MySQL (i hope):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT lc.*, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum
  FROM `langCategories` lc, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  ORDER BY `amount` DESC
)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN rownum <= 8 THEN rownum ELSE 999 END, name
```